# How to install a config file if it does not exist, not overwrite it during upgrade and not delete it during uninstall?

Tags: python, installation, configuration-files, setuptools, setup.py

[As outlined in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-additional-files) I've added the `data_files` variable to `setup.py` to install a config file when the package is installed:

```
setup(...,
      data_files=[('/greg/home/package', ['config']),]
     )
```

**How to install the config file if one does not exist, but not:**

- **uninstall it or**
- **overwrite it during `install --upgrade`?**

For example, when I try to uninstall the package, the config file is included in the list of files to be deleted.

```
$ pip uninstall package
Uninstalling package-0.1.0:
  ...
  /home/greg/package/config
Proceed (y/n)?
```

How to only install config file if one does not exist and use the user's version otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, most packages handle config files like this by only providing an *example* config, and requiring the user to change the filename or move it to a different location so that it won't get overwritten or deleted.

Another thing that some packages will do is provide a command line script to help generate the config (e.g. Sphinx, Django) in a user specified location, instead of packaging a config with the project.